# Como ler um número do teclado sem usar o "enter" em C++

Tags: c++, console, stream

Desejo criar um menu na qual o usuário escolhe a opção de 1 a 5, gostaria que o usuário digitasse o numero e o programa entrasse na opção sem precisar apertar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Segue um exemplo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct pessoa {
    int ID;
    string nome [20];
    string tel [20];
};
typedef struct pessoa P;
int main () {
    int vet[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int opc;    
    do{
    cout<<"[0] incluir pessoa"<<endl;
    cout<<"[1] Alterar pessoa"<<endl;
    cout<<"[2] Excluir pessoa"<<endl;
    cout<<"[4] Recuperar pessoa"<<endl;
    cout<<"[5] Sair"<<endl;
    cin>>opc;
    switch (opc){
        case '0':
        break;
        case '1':
        break;  
        case '2':
        break;
        case '3':
        break;
        case '4':
        break;
        case '5':
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"Opção Invalida"<<endl;   
    }
    }while(opc != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Eu quero ler o `opc` sem o usuário precisar digitar o <kbd>Enter</kbd> e automaticamente cair no `switch-case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente use o [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) do `stream` de entrada. É ele que pega um caractere sem esperar por outros ou uma tecla que finalize.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Pessoa {
    int ID;
    string nome;
    string tel;
}; //isto provavelmente deveria ser uma classe

int main() {
    Pessoa pessoa; //provavelmente deveria ser inicializado por referência e alocado dinamicamente
    char opc = 'z';
    do {
        cout << "[1] incluir pessoa" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Alterar pessoa" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Excluir pessoa" << endl;
        cout << "[4] Recuperar pessoa" << endl;
        cout << "[0] Sair" << endl;
        opc = cin.get();
        switch (opc) {
            case '0':
                break;
            case '1':
                cout << "1" << endl;
                break;  
            case '2':
                cout << "2" << endl;
            break;
            case '3':
                cout << "3" << endl;
                break;
            case '4':
                cout << "4" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Opção Invalida" << endl;
        }
    } while (opc != '0');
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JQgfIk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/euvnredp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/GetChar.cpp).

É uma pena que este código mistura coisas do C. Dei uma organizada.

Comment: Muito obrigado, estou no segundo semestre de S.I e realmente ainda e muito amador os meus codigos, mas o que seria o Typedef para a Struct??  Quando for chamar ela em uma função irei usar tipo cin>>Pessoa.nome??

Comment: Mudei para ficar mais C++ e para mostrar como declarar. Como isto não estava na pergunta original não faz parte do escopo desta, mas é quase isto sim.